# Querying for embedded object inside array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm working on a filter system for a page. I have the following schema structure:

```
User: {
  firstName
  lastName
  email
  subscriptions: [
    {
      id: '5a687c7680eab407064c3990'
      plan: "TRIAL"
      startDate: '2018-03-01'
      endDate: '2018-04-01'
      status: 'EXPIRED'
    }
    {
      id: '5afacc040e53b4075dcdd600'
      plan: "BASIC"
      startDate: '2018-04-01'
      endDate: '2018-05-01'
      status: 'EXPIRED'
    }
    {
      id: '5afacc040e53b4075dcdd600'
      plan: "BASIC"
      startDate: '2018-05-01'
      endDate: '2018-06-01'
      status: 'CANCELLED'
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to get a list of users that have:

- either firstName, lastName or email is 'john'
- current subscriptions status: EXPIRED
- current subscription plan: TRIAL

This should return null.

Here's what I tried:

```
User.find({
  $or:
    [
      { firstName: { $regex: args.search, $options: 'i' } },
      { lastName: { $regex: args.search, $options: 'i' } },
      { email: { $regex: args.search, $options: 'i' } },
    ],
  $and:
    [
      { 'subscriptions.status': 'EXPIRED' },
      { 'subscriptions.plan': 'TRIAL' },
    ],
}).limit(limit).skip(skip);
```

The problem is that I only need to search through the user's latest subscription (the one that has the latest startDate), not every object in the array. Is there a way to do that? I also have a virtual field on the schema, but it seems that you can't query a virtual field.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way to do that through a standard find query. That being said, you can look into the `aggregate()` command and the aggregation pipeline. If you use operators like `$unwind` to turn the array of subscriptions into individual documents, then sort in descending order and grab the first one using the `$first` operator, that should give you what you're looking for. You can then attempt a `$match` using your criteria on that final subdocument.

Comment: @B.Fleming That's not entirely true. We can search the "first" array element without a problem in a regular query. The only thing that needs to happen is to ensure the "latest" is always the first array element when any update is made to the array content. So all this needs is coaxing the OP into actually doing that and they get a very efficient query without using aggregate.

Comment: @NeilLunn This is true, but I'm operating under the assumption that the OP is working with legacy data and lacks the luxury of making that kind of change. Additionally, asynchronous array updates like that can't be made with a safer `$push` operator, so elements could end up missing. Finally, there's the problem of the array not necessarily being in a strict chronological order. Without knowing anything else about these constraints, aggregation is the safest recommendation :)

Comment: @B.Fleming Then don't make the presumption. "Ask the OP instead" which is actually the point of the last comment. Because the OP sees that as well and has the opportunity to respond. And it's not a good or safe recommendation at all.

Comment: Yes, I am working with legacy data that I cannot change and I'm not sure I can assume that the last subscription inside the array will always be the most recent one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try aggregate query to perform this operation...

Firstly you will have to

1. `$match` the firstName, lastName, email
2. then `$unwind` to sort the subscription according to `startDate`
3. then again `$match` to get the plan and status

   ```
   db.collection.aggregate([
     {
       $match: {
         $or: [
           {
             firstName: {
               $regex: args.search,
               $options: "i"
             }
           },
           {
             lastName: {
               $regex: args.search,
               $options: "i"
             }
           },
           {
             email: {
               $regex: args.search,
               $options: "i"
             }
           }
         ]
       }
     },
     {
       $unwind: "$subscriptions"
     },
     {
       $sort: {
         "subscriptions.startDate": -1
       }
     },
     {
       $group: {
         _id: "$_id",
         subscriptions: {
           "$first": "$subscriptions"
         }
       }
     },
     {
       $match: {
         "subscriptions.status": "EXPIRED",
         "subscriptions.plan": "TRIAL"
       }
     },

   ])
   ```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I tried returning an array of users with all their original properties, but I couldn't find a better way than this: http://snippi.com/s/9dcjstv

Comment: look at the `$group`... You need to add more fields there